# Background picture in Navbar not in sync with background of body

Tags: php

I have the wish to show the background picture in my navbar. With a slight darker color.

It works quite well:

[my_website](http://s1001480-2931.mijnreus.nl/justwdowit.com/wdw/)!

I am working with two background pictures. The one I use in Navbar is basically the same as the one in body, but with darker color.

Problem is however: if I make the window smaller, and go to smartphone size, the pictures don't sync anymore.

Maybe I have to add another picture and use a media query?

Comment: Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/about): post the relevant code and add the correct tags, a UI issue is rarely a PHP problem.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add another picture or mdia query. Remove the background image in the `.navbar-inner` and add the following `css` to the `.navbar-inner` class.

```
.navbar-inner
{
    opacity:0.2;
    filter:alpha(opacity=20);
}
```

`opacity` ranges from 0 to 1. filter is for IE8 and below.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have tried that already. The problem is that I don't see the background picture in the Navbar if I scroll downwards. Meaning if have created articles with background, which I do, I see this white background as background in the Navbar. Which is why using another picture is useful.

Comment: Correction of third sentence: .. Meaning if I have created articles with white background... 

I think it has to do with how the image in inner-navbar and image in background resizes by change of height.

Comment: I think all I need is to add the height of the background image to the navbar. So it will resize equally.

Comment: Oh fine, it will be good if you post your solution that works, so that other people may make use of it.